# bit64 integers with fst

Tags: r, data.table, bit64

I have data in a csv containing long integers. I am exchanging this data between csvs and `fst` files.

For example,

```
library(bit64)
library(data.table)
library(fst)
library(magrittr)

# Prepare example csvs
DT64_orig <- data.table(x = (c(2345612345679, 1234567890, 8714567890)))
fwrite(DT64_orig, "DT64_orig.csv")

# Read and move to fst
DT64 <- fread("DT64_orig.csv")
write.fst(DT64, "DT64_fst.fst")

DT_fst2 <- 
  read.fst("DT64_fst.fst") %>%
  setDT

# bit64 integers not preserved:
identical(DT_fst2, DT64)
```

Is there a way to use `fst` files for `data.table`s containing `bit64` integers

Comment: Looks to me that you should be complaining to the maintainer of fst.

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/issues/28

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `fst` might be dropping column attributes either when saving or loading (please ask as an issue on `fst` package). You can put the column types back yourself in the meantime. `bit64::integer64` is a plain `double` under the hood so no bits have been lost.  Just the type information telling R how to print the column.

```
> DT_fst2
               x
1: 1.158886e-311
2: 6.099576e-315
3: 4.305569e-314
> setattr(DT_fst2$x, "class", "integer64")
> DT_fst2
               x
1: 2345612345679
2:    1234567890
3:    8714567890
> identical(DT_fst2, DT64)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Matt is absolutely right, `fst` is currently not serializing any column attributes. It will in the next version though, which is due in a few weeks. At that point, also classes such as `Date` and `POSIXt` will be supported. Supporting custom attributes will be a challenge however, because `fst` provides random access to the data and some attributes are modified upon sub-setting (think time series for example).